# how to charge a dead motorcycle battery?

Tags: motorcycle, battery

I have a 1983 Honda Nighthawk but the battery has died. I also have a trickle charger that you see in this photo but I'm not quite sure what amp and voltage settings I need to use for a motorcycle battery. Is a motorcycle battery significantly different than a car battery? What settings do I need to use?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be 12 volt, and you should always charge at the lowest setting reasonable. In this case I would use the 2 amp setting, 6 amps won't hurt it necessarily but the faster you charge a battery the more you shorten it's life. Other than being smaller the isn't any difference in a car and motorcycle battery

Comment: Other than amperage and reserve capacity, that is ... But that goes right along with the size (direct correlation). +1 my good man.